# How to set API Data in react hook form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, use-form

I have this input field. I am using this input to submit the data for adding new record on server. Now when user wants to edit the data I have to show the API data in this field. How to achieve this?

```
const {
  register,
  handleSubmit,
  formState: { errors },
} = useForm();

const onSubmit = handleSubmit((data) => {
  installNewPlugin(data);
});

 
<form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
  <TextInput
    label="Facebook Analytic Pixel id"
    name="id"
    register={register}
    rules={{ required: "This is a required field" }}
    error={errors?.id?.message}
  />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `defaultValues` prop for `useForm`.
It can be both sync or async.

example:

```
// set default value sync
useForm({
  defaultValues: {
    firstName: 'Anda',
    lastName: 'Man'
  }
})

// set default value async
useForm({
  defaultValues: async () => fetch('/api-endpoint');
})
```

More Info here:
https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform

Comment: the only problem here is that if the call is async (as it usually is) then the form will render before the data has returned, and you'll have the strange result of data being fetched, yet the form appears blank.